# Lib OPAL compilation error

Tags: c++, gcc, compilation, g++, opalvoip

I would like to get some help about compiling OPAL lib in order to build Ekiga from source.
I've installed Ptlib, all right. But when I try installing OPAL, first I do

```
./configure --prefix=/usr
```

It's OK and it creates a Makefile. Then, I do a :

```
make
```

And it says me :

```
test/signalCompare.o: In function `main':
signalCompare.c:(.text.startup+0x36a): undefined reference to `sin'
signalCompare.c:(.text.startup+0x8ed): undefined reference to `log10'
collect2: ld a retourné 1 code d'état d'exécution
make[4]: *** [signalcompare] Erreur 1
make[4]: quittant le répertoire « /home/edouard/Documents/wifi/opal-3.10.2/plugins/audio/SILK/SILK_SDK »
make[3]: *** [SILK_SDK] Erreur 2
make[3]: quittant le répertoire « /home/edouard/Documents/wifi/opal-3.10.2/plugins/audio/SILK »
make[2]: *** [all] Erreur 2
make[2]: quittant le répertoire « /home/edouard/Documents/wifi/opal-3.10.2/plugins »
make[1]: *** [subdirs] Erreur 2
make[1]: quittant le répertoire « /home/edouard/Documents/wifi/opal-3.10.2 »
make: *** [opt] Erreur 2
```

So, I understand that he can't find math.h, if it was a simple gcc file.cpp, I would add -lm option. But how to do with a quite big compilation ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try running the compiler like this...

/home/edouard/Documents/wifi/opal-3.10.2/plugins/audio/SILK/SILK_SDK$ gcc -L./  libSKP_SILK_SDK.a test/signalCompare.o -lSKP_SILK_SDK -o signalcompare -lm

The difference is that the parameter for the math library (-lm) is placed at the end of the command.

Then run make again.

Comment: Opal performed a successful make after I did this (was having the same problem). Thanks